# Weird Java issue in regular If statement

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android App in eclipse and I have this if statement:

```
private static final int MAX_FREQ=2484;
private static final int MIN_FREQ=2412;

if ((freq >= MIN_FREQ) && (freq <= MAX_FREQ)){
        return true;     
    }
```

The `freq` is 2462 and for some odd reason it fails to get into the statement. When I change the source into:

```
private static final int MAX_FREQ=2484;
private static final int MIN_FREQ=2412;

if ((freq >= MIN_FREQ) && (freq <= MAX_FREQ)){
        Log.e(TAG,""Bla Bla");
        return true;     
    }
```

this one works ... :-/ ? What am I missing ?

Comment: The second one can't possibly work: it cannot compile.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, sometimes Eclipses get's confused and it looks like you fixed it by cleaning / rebuilding your project. (I'm assuming those typos are just here in your question.)

Comment: Missing brace in the second statement compile time error

Comment: *What am I missing ?* - `(`

Comment: Compiler optimization gone awry, not retaining the line number?

Comment: Do a clean build of your eclipse project without the Log statement. If you still see the issue then put a breakpoint on the return statement in Debug mode.

Comment: The only different between them are the Log and that's it , all the rest are just typos :-) ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private static final int MAX_FREQ=2484;
private static final int MIN_FREQ=2412;

if ((freq >= MIN_FREQ)  && (freq <= MAX_FREQ)) //missing (
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"Bla Bla"); //Semicolon missing in your code and two " signs together
        return true;     
    }
```